# Erro instalar ionic no ubuntu

Tags: ionic

Quando vou instalar o ionic dar Seguinte erro:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-35-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-0f758453
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-0f758453' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-0f758453' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/douglas/npm-debug.log
```

Obs: Já instalei nodejs e npm.

Comment: node -version retorna alguma coisa? qual comando você está usando? npm install -g cordova ionic ? Tenta rodar com permissao su

Comment: quando digito comando node --version ele retorna a minha versão, isso utilizo do próprio site: http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

Comment: Eu coloco a permissão mesmo assim nada.

Comment: Tenta limpar as instâncias anteriores:

Comment: sudo npm remove -g cordova ionic

Comment: npm cache clean

Comment: e por ultimo instala de novo: sudo npm install -g cordova ionic

Comment: Deu certo. obg.

Comment: Disponha, sendo assim vou responder a pergunta, pra que possa ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente limpar as instalações anteriores:

```
sudo npm remove -g cordova ionic
npm cache clean
```

E por fim instale novamente:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Comment: Obg. Deu tudo certo. Instalou corretamente.